# muParser and VC6

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-6, equations

HI I am trying to use muParser with a legacy MFC application written in VC++6, migrating the code to a later version is not an option.

Has anyone had any success using muParser in this environment. any example source code would be great.

Comment: muParser has already dropped support for VS2003; VC6 is 5 years older than that. I would say that migrating the VC6 code to VS2005 is far easier. If that easy task is already impossible for you, I'd forget about the harder task of backporting muParser into the 20th century.

Answer (score 2):

Migrating the code to a later version really needs to *become* an option. VC 6 is downright *ancient* by today's standards, and support is waning rapidly. The compiler was full of bugs, and they're certainly not getting fixed now. It was the bane of library maintainers for years, and a point in time has finally come when they can drop support for it altogether. Much like with the death of IE 6, there was much rejoicing. It's not very likely that you're going to get muParser to work in VC 6. You'll have much better luck migrating your code forward, and you'll have a *lot* more to show for the effort.

If that's really not possible, you could always compile the muParser library as a DLL in a modern version of Visual Studio and then call it from your VC 6 application.

But that strategy involves its own unique brand of pain, and there seems little reason to struggle through that when you could just port the original MFC app to a modern version of Visual Studio. The MFC libraries are still well-supported by even current versions of VS; you aren't stuck with VC 6 forever.